# INNER JOIN on CTE (Common Table Expression) Without PK

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, common-table-expression

I have a CTE in which I am finding duplicate records matching on 5 columns:

```
    ;WITH DuplicateCount AS
    (
    SELECT 
                   FirstName, 
                   LastName, 
                   DateofBirth,  
                   Email,  
                   c1.Status, 
                   Count(*) AS TotalCount
    FROM Customer c
    INNER JOIN Customer_1 c1 ON c1.customerID = c.customerID
    GROUP BY   FirstName, LastName, DateofBirth, Email, c1.Status
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
```

I am then selecting Status and TotalCount from that CTE and joining an Enum table to produce readable data

```
;WITH DuplicateCount AS
(
SELECT 
               FirstName, 
               LastName, 
               DateofBirth,  
               Email,  
               c1.Status, 
               Count(*) AS TotalCount
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN Customer_1 c1 ON c1.customerID = c.customerID
GROUP BY   FirstName, LastName, DateofBirth, Email, c1.Status
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)

SELECT e.Display, dc.TotalCount
FROM DuplicateCount dc
INNER JOIN Enum e ON dc.Status = e.Index
```

In this scenario, I am able to pull back readable data and use Excel to spit out a graph report of duplicates by Status.

**Problem**

I need to join the `Customer_1` table once again to gather one more column: Stage. Here is how I *tried* to do it:

```
;WITH DuplicateCount AS
(
SELECT         customerID,
               FirstName, 
               LastName, 
               DateofBirth,  
               Email,  
               c1.Status, 
               Count(*) AS TotalCount
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN Customer_1 c1 ON c1.customerID = c.customerID
GROUP BY   customerID, FirstName, LastName, DateofBirth, Email, c1.Status
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)

SELECT e.Display, 
       CASE 
            WHEN c1.Stage = 6 THEN 'First'
            WHEN c1.Stage = 7 THEN 'Second'
            WHEN c1.Stage = 8 THEN 'Third'
            WHEN c1.Stage = 11 THEN 'Fourth'
            WHEN c1.Stage = 9 THEN 'Fifth'
            WHEN c1.Stage = 10 THEN 'Sixth'
            WHEN c1.Stage = 12 THEN 'Unknown'
            ELSE ''
       END AS Stage,
       dc.TotalCount
FROM DuplicateCount dc
INNER JOIN Enum e ON dc.Status = e.Index
INNER JOIN Customer_1 c1 ON c1.customerID = dc.customerID
```

Obviously, that didn't work because none of my records will have duplicate PKs.

Is there a way to join a table to my CTE *without* a PK? Or somehow add a PK to my CTE *without* grouping by it?

**Edit**: This is what I am trying to achieve

| FirstName | LastName | Stage | Total Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Smith | First | 2 |
| John | Smith | Third | 2 |
| Alex | Smith | First | 2 |
| Jane | Smith | Third | 2 |
| Jane | Smith | First | 2 |
| Jack | Smith | Second | 2 |

Then, when reporting on this data:

- John Smith has 4 total records. Two in **First**, two in **Third**
- Alex Smith has 2 total records. Two in **First**
- Jane Smith has 4 total records. Two in **First** and two in **Third**
- Jack Smith has 2 total records. Two in **Second**.

When graphing this data, I should be able to see:

- **First**: 6 total.
- **Second**: 2 total.
- **Third**: 4 total.

Ideally, I could then also bring in CreatedDate and begin to gather data-over-time reports for:

- How many duplicates per Stage.
- How many duplicates per Person.
- How many duplicates for specific date ranges, events, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cardinality of the two sets of data don't match. By that I mean the first set of data with the identified duplicates in is aggregated data across a number of customers (without identifying any customers). You can't then take the multiple separate Customer IDs and attribute them back to the aggregated rows.

I think what you need to do is re-frame what you are trying to get out of your data and work backwards. Post an example set of results that you are trying to achieve.

UPDATE:

It seems you want a list of customer\stage groups with counts?:

```
SELECT     customerID,
           FirstName, 
           LastName, 
           DateofBirth,  
           Email,  
           c1.Status, 
       CASE 
        WHEN c1.Stage = 6 THEN 'First'
        WHEN c1.Stage = 7 THEN 'Second'
        WHEN c1.Stage = 8 THEN 'Third'
        WHEN c1.Stage = 11 THEN 'Fourth'
        WHEN c1.Stage = 9 THEN 'Fifth'
        WHEN c1.Stage = 10 THEN 'Sixth'
        WHEN c1.Stage = 12 THEN 'Unknown'
        ELSE ''
   END AS Stage,
           Count(*) AS TotalCount

FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN Customer_1 c1 ON c1.customerID = c.customerID
GROUP BY   customerID, FirstName, LastName, DateofBirth, Email, c1.Status, c1.Stage
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have edited my original post with the desired outcome. Ultimately, I would like to display duplicates but not match on Stage. I could put Stage in my CTE, however I would not want to `GROUP BY` that, as there may exist duplicates with different stages.

Comment: please can you add a few more example rows for the same and different customers. it's not clear yet what you want to achieve.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because you are correct, the cardinality of what I am looking for doesn't match how I am looking for it. I also realized there were more problems with the data set. Anyway, thank you for your answer.